# how to use relative paths instead of full paths in windows using python

Tags: python, windows

I was wondering how to use relative paths instead of full paths in python. in Linux it is ok but in windows when I try using `./` to indicate relative path it throws me an error saying `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Ender_Bender\\page\\index.html'`. here is my code:

```py
from flask import Flask
from os.path import abspath

app = Flask(__name__)

htmlCode = open(abspath('./page/index.html'),'r')

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return f"""
    {htmlCode}
    """
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

how do I fix this?

Comment: One way is using `__file__` to get the current file path, and editing that.

Comment: when I try to print ```__file__``` it prints nothing

Comment: Oh I actually just saw what you're trying to do, don't do it that way, look up how to use flask templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work:

```py
from os.path import abspath
import os

dirpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
print (dirpath + "\n")
path = os.path.join(dirpath, 'page/index.html')
print (path + "\n")
```